# How do I fix the encoding of the file name downloaded via ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

There is a php-script in php get_dokument, which generates a file called "Инструкция_по_работе_с_сайтом.pdf" (cyrilic) and outputs it to the browser. If I access get_dokument directly in the browser, I get a file called "Инструкция_по_работе_с_сайтом.pdf".
If I use ajax post

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8');
xhr.send($.param({ ajax:1,document_id:document_id,company_id:company_id,action:action}));
```

what I see in Response headers:

```
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Description: File Transfer
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Инструкция_по_работе_с_сайтом.pdf"
Content-Length: 143647
Content-Type: application/pdf; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 07 Sep 2020 08:11:02 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: public
Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
```

But the file opens with the name "Ð_Ð½Ñ_Ñ_Ñ_Ñ_ÐºÑ_Ð¸Ñ__Ð¿Ð¾_Ñ_Ð°Ð±Ð¾Ñ_Ðµ_Ñ__Ñ_Ð°Ð¹Ñ_Ð¾Ð¼.pdf". Using base64 doesn't help

Full code:
PHP:

```
    $name = 'Инструкция_по_работе_с_сайтом';
    $filename_pdf = $name.'.pdf';
    $path = './uploads/dokuments/';
          header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
                header("Content-Type: application/pdf; charset=utf-8");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename_pdf.'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path.$filename_pdf));
    readfile($path.$filename_pdf);
    unlink($path.$filename_pdf);
```

js:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('POST', '<?=site_url('cabinet/dokuments/get_dokument');?>', true);
      xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
      xhr.onload = function () {
          if (this.status === 200) {
              var filename = "";
              var disposition = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
              if (disposition && disposition.indexOf('attachment') !== -1) {
                  var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
                  var matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
                  if (matches != null && matches[1]) filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
              }
              alert(filename);
              var type = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');

              var blob;
              if (typeof File === 'function') {
                  try {
                      blob = new File([this.response], filename, { type: type });
                  } catch (e) { /* Edge */ }
              }
              if (typeof blob === 'undefined') {
                  blob = new Blob([this.response], { type: type });
              }

              if (typeof window.navigator.msSaveBlob !== 'undefined') {
                  // IE workaround for "HTML7007: One or more blob URLs were revoked by closing the blob for which they were created. These URLs will no longer resolve as the data backing the URL has been freed."
                  window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
              } else {
                  var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                  var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

                  if (filename) {
                      // use HTML5 a[download] attribute to specify filename
                      var a = document.createElement("a");
                      // safari doesn't support this yet
                      if (typeof a.download === 'undefined') {
                          window.location.href = downloadUrl;
                      } else {
                          a.href = downloadUrl;
                          a.download = filename;
                          document.body.appendChild(a);
                          a.click();
                      }
                  } else {
                      window.location.href = downloadUrl;
                  }

                  setTimeout(function () { URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl); }, 100); // cleanup
              }
          }
      };
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8');
      xhr.send($.param({ ajax:1,document_id:document_id,company_id:company_id,action:action}));
```

Comment: >But the file opens with the name (gibberish)......What does that mean? Chrome and Windows Explorer see the correct name, but Adobe Reader doesn't read the filename correctly? ......If so, that sounds like a problem with your computer, not your PHP server.

Comment: The pdf file is automatically opened by the browser with the name "Ð_Ð½Ñ_Ñ_Ñ_Ñ_ÐºÑ_Ð¸Ñ__Ð¿Ð¾_Ñ_Ð°Ð±Ð¾Ñ_Ðµ_Ñ__Ñ_Ð°Ð¹Ñ_Ð¾Ð¼.pdf". I tested in Firefox, Opera, Edge, Chrome

Comment: I asked a colleague to check the script on another computer. He got the same result - The pdf file is automatically opened by the browser with the name "Ð_Ð½Ñ_Ñ_Ñ_Ñ_ÐºÑ_Ð¸Ñ__Ð¿Ð¾_Ñ_Ð°Ð±Ð¾Ñ_Ðµ_Ñ__Ñ_Ð°Ð¹Ñ_Ð¾Ð¼.pdf"